# How to put results of cmd to log

Tags: command-line

How to collect command's output/results to the log file? What command can write all msg's in shell to the file?

Answer (score 1):

To put some output to file you can use

```
ls /path_to_folder/ > list.txt
```

This will put output from `ls` command to file with name `list.txt` witch will be created on curent location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream redirection to put output into a file.

```
yourcommand > filename
```

Will create a new file containing the output of yourcommand.

```
anewcommand >> filename
```

Will append the output of anewcommand onto the end of the same file previously used.